# Hoe to embedding mongo charts in react app

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, charts

I am looking for example how to use embedding mongo charts in react app.
[Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/charts/saas/embed-chart-jwt-auth/) - this is mongo example how to do it in plane html js.

Comment: Please check spelling of your title

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.